# Someone can help me with my code in c?

Tags: c, pipe, fork

Iam trying to create a code with 1 parent and 2 childrens. The method recive 3 parameters:
                       original_file word1 word2

The parent read a file line by line:

- If the line is pair, send the line to method proccess_pair and the word1. 
  If the line contains the word1, save the lines in the file_1.txt
- If the line is odd, send the line to method proccess_odd and the word2. 
  If the line contains the word1, save the lines in the file_2.txt

Im beginner in c, and i trying with this:

```
int p_h1[2] // pipe from parent to child1
int p_h2[2];// pipe from parent to child2

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    pid_t pdi1, pdi2;
    FILE *fd; // for original file
    FILE *p_h1f, *p_h2f; //file create for child1 and child2 respectively
    char buffer[1024];//buffer 
    if (pid1<0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error fork \n %s \n",strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    else if (pid1==0){//Im the child1
        //proccess for child 1
        proccess_pair(arg[2]);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
         }
pid2 = fork();
if (pid2<0){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error fork \n %s \n",strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
else if (pid2==0){//Im the child2
        //proccess for child 2
        proccess_odd(arg[2]);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
     }

//Parent dont read from pipe

close(p_h1[0]);
close(p_h2[0]);

fd = fopen(argv[1],"r"); //I openthe file for read it;

p_h1f = fdopen(p_h1[1],"w")
p_h2f = fdopen(p_h2[1],"w")
int i = 1;

while(fgets(buffer,1024,fd) != NULL){
    if (i % 2 ==0){ //check if the lines is pairs
        fputs(buffer,p_h1f);
        fflush(p_h1f);
    }else{
        fputs(buffer,p_h2f);
        fflush(p_h2f);          
    }
    i++;
}
close(p_h1[1]);
close(p_h2[1]);
fclose(fd);
wait(NULL);
wait(NULL);
}
```

Both methods(for chil1 and chil2) will be the same(but closing the correct sides of pipes), for this reason i only implement one of them:

```
void proccess_pair(char *word1){
    FILE *fd;
    fd =  fopen("file_1.txt","w");
    //closing the not used
    close(p_h1[1]);
    close(p_h2[1]);
    close(p_h2[0]);

    int nsto =  dup(1)//duplicate the stdout
    dup2(fd,1);//changing stdout->file_1.txt
    execlp("grep","grep",word1,NULL);//execution of grep
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Im learning and i know that i have many many error, for this reason i need help.

Regards

Comment: If you know how to use a pipe with one children then try to write something for two children and post the code.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès edited! thanks ejeje

Answer (score 0):

> How i can create many pipes in an array in c?

On a POSIX-conformant system, you can do that by calling `pipe()` many times on elements of a 2D array of `int`, as you presented.

> ¿I can use two different pipes(parent-child1,parent-child2)? I can use an array of pipes?

A pipe itself lives only in the kernel.  There is no userspace data 
structure representing a pipe, so you cannot have an array of pipes.

The file descriptors for the pipe *ends*, however, are just `int`s.  The `pipe()` function takes as its argument a pointer to the first element of an array of at least two `int`, and (on success) it writes the appropriate file descriptors into the array.

From a C perspective, there is nothing special about the array in which the pipe ends are to be returned.  In particular, it can be an element of a multi-dimensional array if you so desire.  Or it can be a local variable.  Or it can be a member of a `struct` or a `union`.  Or it can be a large enough block of dynamically-allocated space.  It's not special.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
int new_process(char *word){ // return the writing part of a pipe to a newly created child
  int p[2];
  pipe( p ); // get a new pipe
  if (fork()==0) { // create a new child
    dup2(p[0],0); // child's in is pipe's entry
    close(p[1]);  // close writing part
    execlp("grep","grep",word,NULL); // exec
  }
  close(p[0]); // parent don't need the reading part
  return p[1]; // send back the writing part to caller
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int f1 = new_process(argv[1]); // get the pipe to first child
  int f2 = new_process(argv[1]); // ...second...
  char buffer[1024];//buffer 

  FILE *fd = fopen(argv[1],"r"); // open the file for reading;

  while(fgets(buffer,1024,fd) != NULL) { // read aline
    if (i % 2 ==0) { //check if the line no is pair
      fputs(buffer,f1); // send it to first child
      fflush(f1);
    } else{
      fputs(buffer,f2); // send it to second child
      fflush(f2);          
    }
    i++;
  }
  close(f1);
  close(f2);
  fclose(fd);
  wait(NULL);
  wait(NULL);
}
```

Don't forget to add necessary controls on failures.